# ListView CollectionView sort lowest level

Tags: wpf, sorting, listview

I've a question about how to sort items in a ListView, I thought this would be really easy, but I can't seem to work it out.

The ListView is bound to an observable collection view model... the items in the list view are grouped based on certain properties by setting up a CollectionViewSource and setting up GroupDescriptions:

```
            BrowserItemCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_browser);

        //Set up filter
        BrowserItemCollectionView.Filter = FilterBrowserItems;

        //Set up grouping
        PropertyGroupDescription L1PGD = new PropertyGroupDescription(nameof(BrowserItem.L1group));
        PropertyGroupDescription L2PGD = new PropertyGroupDescription(nameof(BrowserItem.L2group));
        PropertyGroupDescription L3PGD = new PropertyGroupDescription(nameof(BrowserItem.L3group));
        BrowserItemCollectionView.GroupDescriptions.Add(L1PGD);
        BrowserItemCollectionView.GroupDescriptions.Add(L2PGD);
        BrowserItemCollectionView.GroupDescriptions.Add(L3PGD);
```

I then sort the groups with:

```
        //Setup Sorting
        BrowserItemCollectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(nameof(BrowserItem.L1group), ListSortDirection.Descending));
        BrowserItemCollectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(nameof(BrowserItem.L2group), ListSortDirection.Descending));
        BrowserItemCollectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(nameof(BrowserItem.L3group), ListSortDirection.Descending));
```

This works well and sorts the groupings in Descending order.

What I now what to do is sort the actual items - the objects that are the lowest levels of the tree views.

What method do I use to sort the actual list view items?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What method do I use to sort the actual list view items?

You just add another `SortDescription` for a property of the "lowest level" item to `BrowserItemCollectionView.SortDescriptions`:

```
BrowserItemCollectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(
    new SortDescription("PropertyOfItem", ListSortDirection.Descending));
```

Comment: I've tried this, but I have three property groups, so I can add three sort descriptions, the lowest level doesn't have a property group as its the lowest level - I don't see how I can sort the lowest level if it doesn't have a "PropertyOfItem" name to the group... (I hope that names sense!) - Thanks

Comment: What property do you want to sort the lowest level items by? Just replace "PropertyOfItem" with the name of this property.

Comment: Ahhh That worked - Think I was probably over thinking this... Thanks for your help!